# XML Document traversal in java

Tags: java, xml, dom, dom-traversal

which is the most preferable xml document traversal method in java ?  Using `getElementsByTagName` or using `TreeWalker` .

I've one `TreeModel`. a Dom `Node` is the root of the `TreeModel`. There are two `Thread`s adding nodes to it. One `Thread` is adding nodes according the nodes added by the other `Thread`.

e.g.

One `Thread` adding `Node`s named `App`. The other `Thread` adding nodes according to the `name` attribute of the  `Node`s named `App`. Sometimes the nodes are not added correctly. The `TreeModel` only shows the details in the elements by traversing through the nodes.

Note: Adding the `App` `Node` is according to the Name attribute of the `Node`.

Currently for the second `Thread`, the `Node`s are taken by calling `getElementsByTagName`. Is there any advantage by changing it to `TreeWalker` ?

Comment: You should elaborate on your requirements, background and preferences, otherwise this will be very opinion based.

Comment: I've updated the question with my actual requirement

Answer (score 0):

I like XPath.  [W3schools link here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp), [Javadocs here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html).  It is tedious to get started with factories and builders, IMO write your own utility class to save on that tedium.  But the syntax to traverse around is expressive and powerful, and it is a "standard" with good documentation.

If you are brave, check out my [beta Groovy-like xpath-like project](https://github.com/MorganConrad/xen), but I would not propose this as "the most preferable".  :-)

**ADDED**: XPath is a query language for selecting nodes from an XML document.  It is good for *traversing* (moving around in) a DOM structure.  However, OP's updated requirements are for *manipulating / modifying* the DOM structure.  XPath is not a good fit there.